# how to parse floating digits separated by commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have digits of type float and they are comma separated values. I am using the below posted method to check if a string is a comma separated
or not. despite I pass comma separated values the method return false.

Please let me know how to separate digits of type float separated by comma

**input**:

```
11.234,43.456,52.2321,33.2145
```

**code**:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^(\w+)(,\s*\w+)*$")

def check_valid(input_string):
   if pattern.match(input_string) == None:
       print('not a comma separated string')
       return False
   else:
       print('comma separated string')
       return True
```

**results**:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
startAndEndCoord: 11.234,43.456,52.2321,33.2145
not a comma separated string
not a comma separated string
```

Comment: What's `pattern`? What's in the input file? What's calling `check_valid`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the question is updated

Comment: `"11.234,43.456,52.2321,33.2145".split(",")`?

Comment: The last sentence is a bit unclear. So to be sure, what you want is to know how to detect if a float value has a comma in it or not?

Of just how to split a long float number by the comma's?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `split()`?

For example:

```
s = "11.234,43.456,52.2321,33.2145"
print(s.split(","))
```

Output:

```
['11.234', '43.456', '52.2321', '33.2145']
```

Comment: these values are to be entered in a url so they change

Comment: Can you share a sample of input values?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the string input contains any comma, you can use `split()` function like the following code:

```
def isContainComma(input_string):
    arr=input_string.split(",")
    if len(arr)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can test the code:

```
input_string="11.234,43.456,52.2321,33.2145"
print(isContainComma(input_string))
```

> True